# осуществить редирект поисковиков с одного адреса на другой

Tags: .htaccess

Для поисковиков осуществить редирект через .htaccess на пререндер. Пререндер настроен, но редирект не происходит. Вот мой код:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
   #Enable prerendering for .html and directory index files
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot|bingbot|Googlebot-Mobile|Baiduspider|Yahoo|YahooSeeker|DoCoMo|Twitterbot|TweetmemeBot|Twikle|Netseer|Daumoa|SeznamBot|Ezooms|MSNBot|Exabot|MJ12bot|sogou\sspider|YandexBot|bitlybot|ia_archiver|proximic|spbot|ChangeDetection|NaverBot|MetaJobBot|magpie-crawler|Genieo\sWeb\sfilter|Qualidator.com\sBot|Woko|Vagabondo|360Spider|ExB\sLanguage\sCrawler|AddThis.com|aiHitBot|Spinn3r|BingPreview|GrapeshotCrawler|CareerBot|ZumBot|ShopWiki|bixocrawler|uMBot|sistrix|linkdexbot|AhrefsBot|archive.org_bot|SeoCheckBot|TurnitinBot|VoilaBot|SearchmetricsBot|Butterfly|Yahoo!|Plukkie|yacybot|trendictionbot|UASlinkChecker|Blekkobot|Wotbox|YioopBot|meanpathbot|TinEye|LuminateBot|FyberSpider|Infohelfer|linkdex.com|Curious\sGeorge|Fetch-Guess|ichiro|MojeekBot|SBSearch|WebThumbnail|socialbm_bot|SemrushBot|Vedma|alexa\ssite\saudit|SEOkicks-Robot|Browsershots|BLEXBot|woriobot|AMZNKAssocBot|Speedy|oBot|HostTracker|OpenWebSpider|WBSearchBot|FacebookExternalHit [NC,OR]
    #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_|prerender=1
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Prerender
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://prerender.schuchin.info:3000/http://schuchin.info/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас некорретно записано правило для RewriteCond

Попробуйте вот так

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot [OR]
....
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} FacebookExternalHit
```

Или же

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (Googlebot|bingbot|...|FacebookExternalHit)
```

Comment: @newmab <code><IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
    #Enable prerendering for .html and directory index files
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_|prerender=1
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Prerender
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://prerender.schuchin.info:3000/http://schuchin.info/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule></code>не работает ваш вариант(

Comment: @temxby тогда вопрос в том как проверяете, что не работает. На основании чего делаете вывод работает редирект или нет?

Comment: @newmab в браузере меняю юзер агент на гугловский, перехожу на сайт и редирект не идет.